# If $Ax<x$, then $A^n \to 0$

Tags: matrices

If $Ax<x$ where $A \in M_n({\mathbb R})$ nonnegative matriz and $x$ is a column matrix positive, show that:

$$A^n \to 0, \mbox{when } n \to \infty$$

I can obtain that the digaonal's coefficient are smaller that one, but not necessarily the rest. Help me, please.

Comment: what do you mean by $Ax < x$?

Comment: That x - Ax is a positive matrix

Comment: Hint: $\|A^n\| \leq \|A\|^n$ so all we need is $\| A\| <1$. To show this all you need to do is show that $\| A x \| < \| x\|$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$; you are already half-way there with the first assumption (I am assume $A x < x$ is the order on the coordinates).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hint.* Prove by mathematical induction that there is some $0<c<1$ that makes $A^nx\le c^nx$ for every $n\ge1$.

Comment: and for all $x \in R^{nx1}$?

Comment: @JhonKevinAstoquillcaAguilar No, the question only says that $Ax<x$ for some $x$. We use that $x$ here.

Comment: Ok, i already solved the exercise, thanks a lot.